# Installation failed when attempting to reinstall MySQL in OS X 10.6.6

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mysql

I had earlier installed mysql-5.1.50-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg and then uninstalled it using the below command (found on Stack Overflow):

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/mysql  
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM   
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*   
$ rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*   
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*   
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*   
$ sudo vi /etc/hostconfig   
$ sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.mysql*   
$ cd /Library/Receipts/
```

Then I have tried to reinstall from mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg.

However I am getting the following error:

> The installation failed
>   The installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.

Comment: Can you open `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app` and tell us, what the errors are from the MySQL installer?

Comment: Console does not show any thing related to mysql but related to office 2008. How ever the installer log showed:Feb 21 21:30:28 Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro Installer[378]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 UserInfo=0x11940f8d0 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg”." –

Comment: At which point of the installation does the error occur? Did you follow these steps? <http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/macosx-installation-pkg.html>

Comment: yes, i have followed the complete steps, in the last part, the error occurs, last time when I have installed it was perfect. I guess i need to remove something prior installing. Please help. To be precise in the installation step.

Comment: I am breaking my head over it, don't have any clue how to fix it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-post of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067787/re-install-mysql-in-mac-os-x-10-6-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to instal MySQL at last. Details can be found @
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067787/re-install-mysql-in-mac-os-x-10-6-6

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late, but [Homebrew for Macintosh](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/) is a **stellar** way to install software such as mysql. There is information on the their wiki on how to install and then once brew is installed, it is just `brew install mysql` in your terminal window.

Good luck!

Update: DOH. I fail at reading. Problem already solved. Anyway, for people in the future, if you have trouble installing mysql, give brew a try.

Comment: Definitely agree with you. Homebrew is, IMHO, the best package management system anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install MySql from the CD that come with your computer. It is part of apple developer tools. Once that is installed, try to install the dmg you downloaded from the official site.

Comment: I have received only 2 DVD, one is of os x install and the other is application DVD, I did not get which one are to talking about.

Comment: if you mount one of those DVD's there's an installer with apple development tools. I don't have DVDs with me at the moment.